# maxn is not exact multiple of this j column's length when plotting histogram from data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to plot a histogram from the results of a data.table grouping but seem to be unable to get more than one chart produced before the follow error occurs:

> Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , hist(V2, breaks = 2), by = V1) :    maxn
>   (3) is not exact multiple of this j column's length (2)

This toy example should hopefully demonstrate the problem

```
require( data.table ) 
DT = data.table(c(1,1,2,2), c(1,2,3,4))

# This works
DT[,plot(V2,V2), by = V1] 

# This fails after the first plot
DT[,hist(V2, breaks = 2), by = V1]
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the `j` expression in `list`. If I find (or remember) the reason why I will edit it in...

```
DT[, list( hist(V2,breaks = 2) ) , by = V1 ]
```

Comment: Works a treat, thanks for the speedy answer. Would be interested to know why this is required if anyone has any insight!

Comment: @SimonWalker I have asked one of the developers on chat. Hopefully he will respond (not his timezone at the mo though I believe).

Comment: I think it's because `plot` returns `NULL`, whereas 'hist' does not. And results in error because length returned is different for each group. Wrapping in 'list' makes the new column 'list' type.